# how to make is index formal in excel returning more than 1 result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

{=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3)*(C1=range4),0))}
how to make this code returning more than 1 result

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple match criterion (which won't actually return more than 1 result, if anything, the result will be narrower / more restrictive sine multiple matches operate as a product - thereby returning the intersection of the results (I'll include away to return something similar but 'or' i.e. union of results if requested...

Screenshots refer:

[[image: SSiSmple mu;lto;e screesjpt]

---

Pro: mainstream/ straightforward; match enables wildcard chars "*"&word&"*" ee.g.

Con:  only returns first match found